# Is there a relation between the magnetic field force of the earth and the gravitational force between the earth and other bodies?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, magnetic-fields

According to Newton's Universal Law of gravitation, we can say that a huge body of mass will attract another body of mass within a short range, however, if both bodies are for instance magnetic, wouldn't there be a repelling/attracting force between the bodies? Since both the earth and the sun are known to have their own magnetic fields why isn't this represented in the universal gravitation law?

Comment: A trivial answer is this: if we wanted to take magnetic effects into account, it wouldn't be called the universal *gravitation* law ;-) Actually, there isn't really another answer. Of course, magnetic effects should be taken into account if there are any, but the universal gravitation law only deals with the gravitational force, hence the name ;-)

Comment: So does this mean that the universal gravitational law alone cannot be used to calculate the total forces actings between the earth and the sun for instance?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it means.  Calculating the total force involves finding all of the forces and adding up their influences.  Gravity is just one; there are three others that are known to us at the time (E&M, Strong, Weak).  Strong and Weak forces are meaningless at these distance scales...but one could imagine bodies where the Electromagnetic Forces may rival gravitational forces.  The reason why we don't consider E&M forces is because while gravity always attracts, E&M forces repel and attract half of the time, so their total contribution is more or less 0.

Comment: At the earth/sun scales, then, only gravity is really important.  You could say that it's not "all" of the forces, but for all useful purposes, we only have to consider gravity.  In fact the E&M attraction is so miniscule that we probably don't even have instruments to measure it.

Comment: @JustinL. So then, how come the mass of the sun is calculated based on simply the distance from the earth and mass of the earth if there is more than just gravitational force acting between the two? Shouldn't there be at least more than one uncertainty in the variables?

Comment: Also is their a constant measure or formula for finding out the magnetic force of a body? If there is not, can you say at their scale only gravity is important?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Let's say that we know the mass of the sun is 1.98855 +/- 0.00025 x 10^30 kg.  let's say one day someone tries to calculate the "true" mass of the sun taking into account EM forces and they get a result that changes the mass of the sun by say 10^20 kg.  Would this change our answer about the mass of the sun?  No; our uncertainty is already much bigger.  We don't know the exact E&M force that the earth exerts on the sun but we do know that it can't be bigger than a certain limit...and that limit is much smaller than the uncertainty in our current measurements, so we ignore it.

Comment: And yes there are exact formulas for finding the strength attraction caused by E&M forces.

Comment: @JustinL My major problem is, if we do not know the magnetic force of the sun for certain -- [this website for instance does claim it is still ongoing research](http://www.windows2universe.org/sun/sun_magnetic_field.html), does it mean that we can determine the mass of the sun? And since many theories are based on this, wouldn't it in some way affect a lot of other theories?

Comment: We don't know the exact strength, but we do know how big it can possibly be.  It's like saying we don't know the exact height of an ant down to the micrometer ... but we do know it's shorter than a skyscraper, or taller than an atom.  So when we calculate the height of a skyscraper, we don't consider "what if there is an ant at the top?" -- the "height" we write down in the books would be the same if we included the ant or not...and we wouldn't be arguing about how tall the ant "truly" is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9349/discussion-between-chibueze-opata-and-justin-l)

Answer (score 2):

There are many forces that act between the Sun and the Earth. If you were to sketch out the full equation for the attractive force between them it would look something like this:
$$
F = \text{gravitational force}\\
- \text{force due to radiation pressure exerted on the Earth by the Sun}\\
- \text{force due radiation pressure exerted on the Sun by reflected light from Earth}\\
+ \text{electrostatic attraction (if they have opposite charges overall)}\\
- \text{electrostatic repulsion (if they have the same charge overall)}\\
+/- \text{attraction or repulsion due to magnetic dipole effects}\\
- \text{force exerted by Solar wind on Earth}\\
- \text{a fictitious force due to the expansion of space in between them}\\
+/- \text{any others I've forgotten.}\\
$$
The thing is that the first term in this equation, the gravitational attraction, is so enormously bigger than all the others that they just don't really make any difference in comparison to it.

Actually the second term (radiation pressure exerted on the Earth) is just about big enough to make a measurable difference. If I recall correctly, this force is about equal to the weight of an ocean liner. But if you imagine how much smaller an ocean liner is than the Earth, you'll start to get an idea of how small the radiation pressure force is in comparison to the gravitational one. The other terms in the equation are even smaller than that. You could try taking them into account in a model, but the difference it would make would be so tiny that it would be swamped by numerical errors and uncertainty.

So on the one hand you're right that the magnetic force exists, but on the other hand there is a principled reason why it's never taken into account in models.

Answer (score 0):

> Since both the earth and the sun are known to have their own magnetic
>   fields why isn't this represented in the universal gravitation law?

There appear to be only two long-range (macroscopic) interactions:  the gravitational interaction and the electromagnetic interaction.

It used to be thought that the electric and magnetic interactions were two distinct interactions but, in the 19th century, it was shown that in fact, the electric and magnetic interactions are aspects of a single electromagnetic interaction.

Numerous unsuccessful attempts have been made to unify the gravitational and electromagnetic interactions into a unified, single interaction.

***However, to the extent of our current knowledge, the two interactions are not related and so, must be treated by separate, distinct "laws".***